# What does [variable0 for variable1 in variable2] mean in python

Tags: python

I got confused of this syntax. Is it still a list? so why putting a for statement in a list?
[The code comes from here](https://discussions.udacity.com/t/assignment-1-problem-5/45657/13?u=zion93)

Comment: This is a list comprehension.  Use that term in your search for explanation.

Comment: @VedangMehta I think this is a perfectly valid question for a beginner. What's wrong?

Comment: Googling `Python for statement in a list` turns up an explanation of the syntax immediately. Remember, Google won't laugh at you if you give it the wrong terminology, and it'll usually guide you to the right terminology. Don't be afraid to search.

Comment: @AlexHall Multiple reasons. Calling list comprehension `[variable0 for variable1 in variable2]`, writing "dose" instead of "does" and posting a link of code snippet which you can't even see without signing into Udacity.

Comment: @VedangMehta (1) That is precisely why they are asking the question, they don't know what it's called. (2) People make typos and such. (3) It's easy to not be aware of that when you are signed in. Have some empathy.

Comment: @AlexHall I didn't downvote the question. Isn't it better for everyone at SO if the quality of questions is better?

Comment: @VedangMehta it is but it's also not nice to falsely imply that someone sucks at asking. You wouldn't post that link on every question just in case reading it made things better. The question was reasonable and had two minor mistakes.

Comment: @AlexHall I might have overreacted.

Answer (score 0):

It's a way of generating a list on the fly, called a List Comprehension.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Thank you. That helps a lot.